# Why is image not showing up in browser when I use sublime editor? using <img src=""> Link to see code http://screencast.com/t/vd5WCoInVYn

Tags: html, css, image

I've also tried to upload images without the .css at the end of the folder and it doesn't work either.

This is a similar code using teamtreehouse editor http://screencast.com/t/LtJuxDd8 and here is the results http://screencast.com/t/tgg2zRNfWb

Comment: @sergiureznicencu Instead of just saying I'm wrong you can offer a useful solution, like I mentioned in my question writing it like that has worked in other text editors. I'm just having a problem with it working in sublime editor, so if you don't have any useful solutions, then your statement is not needed.

Comment: @Kld I just tried that and it's still not showing up the image.  I'm still seeing this http://screencast.com/t/7TdhwIBVhDsz

Answer (score 0):

Where is your index.html?

Your index has to be outside of the folder with the image files

Comment: the index.html is in a separate file but it's not in a folder. This is a similar code using teamtreehouse editor http://screencast.com/t/LtJuxDd8 and here is the results http://screencast.com/t/tgg2zRNfWb